# Macro expansion ignores token `let` and any following

Tags: rust, macros

I want to define a variable with a macro `ident` and pass it to a derive macro, but I get an error:

**Error**

```
error: macro expansion ignores token `let` and any following
  --> database/src/models.rs:15:9
   |
15 |           let struct_name = stringify!($name);
   |           ^^^
...
50 | / model!(Person {
51 | |     name: String
52 | | });
   | |___- caused by the macro expansion here
   |
   = note: the usage of `model!` is likely invalid in item context
```

**Code**

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! model {
    ( 
        $(#[$met: meta])*
        $name: ident { $($attr: ident : $typ: ty),* } 
    ) => {

        let struct_name = stringify!($name);
        //let table_name = struct_name.to_camel_case();
        
        dbg!("{}", struct_name);
        
        #[derive(Debug)]
        struct $name {
            name: String
        };
    };
}

model!(Person {
        name: String
});
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d65e362add67b251549dba28f546705)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the macro `model!` where the compiler expects an item (function/struct/trait declaration or `impl` block). A `let` statement is only valid inside a code block. This is why your [first example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=72fec6b7a42fdeead3345f35f4e8eacc) works (where the macro call is inside `main`), while your [second example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d65e362add67b251549dba28f546705) doesn't.

This seems like an instance of the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Check out [procedural macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html) if you want to run code to generate code at compile time.